# What was the military significance of Sherman's reaching Chattahoochee River near Atlanta?

Tags: american-civil-war

The political significance was that Confederate President Jefferson Davis replaced General Joseph E. Johnston in command with General John Bell Hood.

Earlier, Johnston had been following a [strategy](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/8186/what-were-general-johnstons-options-during-the-atlanta-campaign) of wasting Sherman's strength in savage skirmish battles (although Kennesaw Mountain was more than a skirmish), and retreating to force Sherman to lengthen his lines of communication, while shortening Johnston's. By the time they approached Atlanta, the strengths of the Union and Confederate armies were more equal than was usually the case.

Then Sherman shocked the South by crossing the Chattahoochee River, approaching Peach Tree Creek, threatening Atlanta directly. I would have thought that the Chattahoochee River might be a good place for Johnston on confront him head-on. Except that Johnston waited for a crossing of Peachtree Creek instead. Why might he have done so?

Was letting Sherman cross Chattahoochee River without opposition a viable part of Johnston's "Fabian" strategy? Or was it an oversight on Johnston's part that constituted good grounds for relieving him?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Johnston was going to attack, but he was removed before the attack took place and Hooker executed the attack in his stead, no? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Peachtree_Creek

Comment: @Allure: I'm sorry. I had confused "Peachtree Creek" with the Chattohoochee River. Fixed the question.

Comment: Have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnston%27s_River_Line and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sope_Creek#Civil_War_history ?